# How to only add item from list if item in different list is not 0 keeping same index?

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am working with Excel (using xlsxwriter and openpyxl) and I am trying to populate cells of one column from one list based on if the cell in the adjacent column has a 0 in it or not. If said adjacent column cell has a 0 in it, the code should  ignore whatever number is in the second list and replace that with a 0 in the new cell.

To simplify my code, here is what I am working with, just less numbers. I have two lists:

```
full[2, 5, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0]
regr[3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3]
```

List `full` is displayed in Excel's column `B`, one list item per cell. What I need to do is display the items fro list `regr` in the next column `C`, replacing current numbers with `0` if `0` is found in the adjacent cell in column `B`.

So it should ideally look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ0HG.png

What I am finding difficult is having a loop that keeps track of the index of each list, and a counter that adds each time (for column insertion purposes - `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, `B4` etc.)

I have code that populates column `B` with the `regr` list but it doesn't do the `0` check and all my attempts to store and use the `index` have failed.

```
for x in range(0, 50):
        worksheet1.write("B" + str(x), str(regr[x]))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `zip` to loop over the two lists in parallel. Also, don't try and create cell coordinates programmatically using the "A1" syntax. Both openpyxl and xlsxwriter allow the use of numeric row and column indices for this kind of thing.